# std::basic_stream not supporting char16_t in Xcode (OS X target)

Tags: c++, xcode, clang, sentry, istream

First, I want to predicate this issue as only being a problem on OS X using Xcode and the clang compiler.  The following code compiles with gcc (9 and 10) on Linux (RH8) and Visual Studio (2019).  However it will not compile on Xcode (13.1) with clang on Big Sur targeting OS X.

```cpp
std::basic_fstream<char16_t> stream;

rapidjson::BasicIStreamWrapper<std::basic_fstream<char16_t>> iwrapper(stream);

rapidjson::GenericStreamWrapper<
  rapidjson::BasicIStreamWrapper<std::basic_fstream<char16_t>>,
                                  rapidjson::UTF16<char16_t>> gwrapper(iwrapper);
```

I believe the use of the rapidjson library here is irrelevant to the issue.

When I try to use `gwrapper`, I get a compiler error:

```
No matching constructor for initialization of 'std::basic_istream<char16_t>::sentry'
...
13. Candidate constructor not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided
```

This appears to come from the stream's constructor:

```cpp
template<class _CharT, class _Traits>
typename basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::int_type
basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::get()
{
    ios_base::iostate __state = ios_base::goodbit;
    __gc_ = 0;
    int_type __r = traits_type::eof();
    sentry __s(*this, true); <---- HERE
...
```

Pointing to line 297 (at least Apple's version of the file) of `istream`.  This is where a single argument constructor sentry is defined.

```cpp
template <class _CharT, class _Traits>
class _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::sentry
{
    bool __ok_;

    sentry(const sentry&); // = delete; <-- ERROR POINTS HERE
    sentry& operator=(const sentry&); // = delete;

public:
    explicit sentry(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& __is, bool __noskipws = false);
//    ~sentry() = default;

    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
        _LIBCPP_EXPLICIT
        operator bool() const {return __ok_;}
};
```

It appears to want the explicitly defined constructor:

```cpp
explicit sentry(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& __is, bool __noskipws = false);
```

That datatype is `char16_t` for the stream, and hence for the sentry as well.  The compiler isn't picking the correct constructor. At least, that is my conclusion at this point.  I find it unlikely that a system header file or the system library is incorrectly written (though not impossible), leaving me wondering what I am doing wrong.

As requested I tried it without the library code.  Different error but still points to the same place.

The new code ..

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <ctype.h>



int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    
    std::basic_fstream<char16_t> s;
    s.peek();
    return 0;
}
```

The errors...

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/istream:325:26: Implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::ctype<char16_t>'
/Users/user/dev/cti/cti/clang_tests/clang_tests/main.cpp:6:10: in file included from /Users/user/dev/cti/cti/clang_tests/clang_tests/main.cpp:6:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/fstream:185:10: in file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/fstream:185:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/istream:1018:12: In instantiation of member function 'std::basic_istream<char16_t>::sentry::sentry' requested here
/Users/user/dev/cti/cti/clang_tests/clang_tests/main.cpp:15:7: In instantiation of member function 'std::basic_istream<char16_t>::peek' requested here
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:519:52: Template is declared here
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:254:54: Implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::ctype<char16_t>'
/Users/user/dev/cti/cti/clang_tests/clang_tests/main.cpp:6:10: in file included from /Users/user/dev/cti/cti/clang_tests/clang_tests/main.cpp:6:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/fstream:184:10: in file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/fstream:184:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/ostream:137:10: in file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/ostream:137:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/ios:215:10: in file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/ios:215:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/istream:321:41: In instantiation of function template specialization 'std::use_facetstd::ctype<char16_t>' requested here
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/istream:1018:12: In instantiation of member function 'std::basic_istream<char16_t>::sentry::sentry' requested here
/Users/user/dev/cti/cti/clang_tests/clang_tests/main.cpp:15:7: In instantiation of member function 'std::basic_istream<char16_t>::peek' requested here
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:519:52: Template is declared here

Comment: "*I believe the use of the rapidjson library here is irrelevant to the issue*" - then can you provide a [mcve] that doesn't depend on external libraries?